# jQuery Checkbox Selector With Multi Attributes

Tags: jquery, attributes, checkbox, selector

I've got a jQuery selector thats not working desipte my best efforts to fix it. Any advice?

```
            $(':checkbox:(not(:checked))[name=this.name][value="Done"]').attr({
                checked: 'checked',
                disabled: 'disabled'
            });
```

It should check and disable a checkbox if it's not already checked, has a name attribute = this.name and a value of Done.

I've been fiddling around with it http://jsfiddle.net/PottyMonster/s8RMJ/   I dunno if that'll work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('input[name=' + this.name + '][value=Done][type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').attr({
    checked: 'checked',
    disabled: 'disabled'
});
```

**Updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/s8RMJ/22/

You need to concatenate the value of `this.name` into the selector.

I also added `input` to the selector to make it faster.

Also, you had an extra `()` around the `:not()` so it looked like `:(not())` which isn't valid.

---

**EDIT:**

Just wanted to note that I had replaced the `:checkbox` selector with `[type=checkbox]` in order to make your selector valid for `querySelectorAll`.

Now it will get a big performance boost in browsers that support `qsa`.

Answer (score 0):

change `[name=this.name]` to `[name="'+this.name+'"]`
and `:checkbox` to `[type="checkbox"]`
http://jsfiddle.net/s8RMJ/24/